# How to specify the version of Chef Solo in Test Kitchen .kitchen.yml file?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I am using Test Kitchen to test a cookbook. I would like to specify the version number of chef solo that will be installed. How can I specify a version number?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured it out...In your `.kitchen.yml` file you have an option called `require_chef_omnibus`. You can specify `true`, `latest`, or a version number.

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  require_chef_omnibus: 11.10.4
```

Comment: The documentation at https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html doesn't mention the option `latest`. But it works as described here.

Answer (score 2):

```
       **** require_chef_omnibus deprecated
The 'require_chef_omnibus' attribute with version values will change
to use the new 'product_version' attribute.

Note: 'product_name' must be set in order to use 'product_version'
until 'product_name' replaces 'require_chef_omnibus' as the default.

# New Usage #
provisioner:
  product_name: <chef or chefdk>
  product_version: 13.12.3
```

Comment: Don't forget to set product_name when using it else this option will be silently ignored.